Wrongly cancelling a service - which issur, if any?
When someone cancels a transaction and in order to save on any associated fees, they lie about the reason

Which issur (if any) is being transgressed?
Does it matter if the merchant is Jewish or not?

I'll give an example: on some of the parking apps there is a fee to cancel the booked parking spot if cancelled after a certain time. This fee is waived if the cancelation is because the parking lot is full. What if a person, didn't end up parking in the lot and in order to not have to pay the fees lied by saying that the lot was full.
To further clarify: the parking app charges the credit card the full amount at time of booking and will fully refund if cancelled prior to the begin of the booking time. Throughout the sign-up process to the app one has to accept their terms.
My question is about monetary issurim, not about the issur of lying

The analysis might be different if it is a government operated lot (i.e. a certain amount of accepted corruption baked into the equation גזלנותא דמלכותא might mean it is equitable and expected to "cheat" the system back).

@Deuteronomy is your comment "if it is a government operated lot (i.e. a certain amount of accepted corruption baked into the equation" intended seriously?

@EdwardB Yes (15 char)

If I understand the question correctly, the answer is well summarised in this article Theft And Deception by Rabbi Doniel Neustadt
The essence of the article's conclusion is in this short passage:

It is strictly forbidden to deceive or trick any merchant, Jewish or
not. Doing so is considered “stealing” min ha-Torah which is forbidden
without any exception...

I have tried hard to understand the facts of the question but have not been entirely successful.
The "terms of the parking app" cited as an example by the OP are:

the parking app charges the credit card the full amount at time of
booking and will fully refund if cancelled prior to the begin[ing] of the
booking time

There appear to be two possibilities:
either
(a) cancellation is permitted prior to the commencement of the booking for any reason; or
(b) cancellation is permitted prior to the commencement of the booking only if the parking lot is full.
If the fact pattern of the question posed by the OP is (b), then lying about the reason for cancellation is deception and such conduct is stealing as set out in the short extract above from Theft And Deception by Rabbi Doniel Neustadt.
If the fact pattern is (a), then although the customer has deceived the merchant, the deception has not caused the merchant any loss as the cancellation was permitted in any event under the terms of the transaction. Still morally wrong but perhaps not contrary to halacha.

Don't I need to "take" something by way of kinyan gzeila or gneiva- in my case nothing was taken from the other. Rabbi neustatadt doesn't address that. I don't disagree about the immorality.

I assumed that what the question was looking at was something like cancelling a parking transaction after 3 minutes not because the lot was full but because all that was required was 3 minutes parking to pop in and out of a store.

@Yoreinu The buyer (parker) is taking the fee which rightfully belongs to the seller (lot owner)

@DoubleAA in order to rightfully belong to the lot owner, wouldn't there have to be some type of binding Kinyan?

@Yoreinu there was a kinyan when the parker bought the pass. If I buy groceries and take them to my car and refuse to pay, that's clearly not ok, right?

@DoubleAA  that would be a kinyan Meshicha and would indeed be a problem. There was no meshicha involved here.

@Yoreinu The pass was also bought somehow. Maybe clicking accept? You haven't explained exactly how things went down.

@DoubleAA i added further details.

@Yoreinu extra details just complicate the question post. You'd probably do better to just stipulate if there's a kinyan or not and then ask separately what constitutes a kinyan in this kind of transaction
